# Building GUI Applications in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is there a free equivalent to the Sapien Powershell Studio to build GUI applications in Powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution:
There is a free community edition of Powershell studio which is called PrimalFormsCE.

http://www.sapien.com/software/freetools#PrimalFormsCE

You can build GUI applications, then export to Ps1, edit the code...
Really a good tool !